# Scandinavien characters in mysql are not shown correctly

Tags: mysql, linux, character-encoding

I have a problem when inserting in a table in my database. The server running is Ubuntu:

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise

I have created a database with one table the following way:

Database creation
mysql>create  database test1234  CHARACTER SET latin1;

Table creation
mysql>create table testtbl (test varchar(22)  CHARACTER SET latin1);

Insert
mysql>insert into testtbl (test) values ('asdsdaæø');

Selecter:
mysql> select * from testtbl;

+--------------+ 
| test         |
+--------------+
|              |
| asdsda       |
| Ã¦Ã¸Ã¥          |
| Ã¦Ã¸Ã¥          |
| asdadsÃ¦Ã¸Ã¥    |
+--------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.29, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2

Connection id:          427
Current database:       test1234
Current user:           root@localhost
SSL:                    Not in use
Current pager:          stdout
Using outfile:          ''
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.2-log (Ubuntu)
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             Localhost via UNIX socket
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    latin1
Client characterset:    latin1
Conn.  characterset:    latin1
UNIX socket:            /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime:                 12 days 19 hours 9 min 35 sec

I have also tried with utf8 but with the same result.

From /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
130421 18:03:06   427 Query     insert into testtbl (test) values ('asdads')
130421 18:03:08   427 Query     select * from testtbl

I have searched close to the whole Internet but without any luck to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You probably have a browser/SQL client running UTF-8, while the DB data is in Latin-1.**

When dealing with character encodings, you have to be certain that all steps from the datasource to your screen are using the same encoding. This includes:

- Encoding of the data sent in to your database
- Encoding of the database
- Encoding of the file/script reading from your database

If the end point is a web page:

- Encoding set in the HTTP headers
- Encoding set in meta tags
- Web browser encoding settings (should be automatically set to match HTTP header/meta tags)

A good tip is to always use UTF-8, if you don't really need to use latin1. UTF-8 is more and more becoming the standard everywhere, and most applications uses it as a standard.

Comment: AS I posted:

Server characterset: latin1
Db characterset: latin1
Client characterset: latin1
Conn. characterset: latin1

For now I am only inserting and selecting data directly from the mysql clinet

Comment: @user2304731 What character set is your linux console running? (`locale` at the command prompt)

Comment: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Comment: I have now changed it to UTF8 in mysql:

mysql>  show variables like 'char%';
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
character_set_system     | utf8                       |

Comment: I found the problem.
I changed the everything to utf8 but it was still not working. Then I found out that Putty was set to latin1. I changed it to utf8 and now it's working like a charm.

Thanks